# How to go through the elements of type string

Tags: swift, string, character

I am writing a function that should return the number of duplicates. I can’t understand how to go through the elements of type string.

```
func countDuplicates(_ s:String) -> Int {
    var duplicates = 0

    for i in s {
        duplicates += 1
    }

    return duplicates
}
```

Comment: You ARE go through the elements of String. What is your problem then ?

Comment: I need to find duplicate characters in a string

Comment: There is no sight of trying in the question. Just keep track of the appearance of each character.

Comment: @EgorGorskikh Are you only trying to count a number of characters which are duplicate? Or do you want to know specifically which of them are duplicates?

Comment: @pawello2222 count the number of repeated characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
func countDuplicates(_ s:String) -> Int {
    return s.count - Set(s).count
}
```

Where:

```
s.count // total number of characters
Set(s).count // number of unique characters
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the total sum of duplicates, the code below could be helpful:

```
let text = "HelloooE"
func numberOfDuplicates(_ s: String) -> Int { s.count - Set(s).count }

print(numberOfDuplicates(text)) //Answer: 3 >> which says one "l" and two "o"s are duplicated.
```

But if the count of duplicated characters is required, this should be the answer:

```
let text = "HelloooE"
func countOfDuplicateChars(_ s: String) -> Int { 
    s.reduce(into: [:]) {result, word in result[word, default: 0] += 1 }
     .filter { $0.value > 1 }
     .count 
}

print(countOfDuplicateChars(text)) //Answer: 2 >> which says "l" and "o" are duplicated characters.
```

The function below is also return the count of duplicated characters and also is case insensitive:

```
let text = "HelloooE"
func countOfDuplicateChars_CS(_ s: String) -> Int {
    s.lowercased()
     .reduce(into: [:]) {result, word in result[word, default: 0] += 1 }
     .filter { $0.value > 1 }
     .count
 }

print(countOfDuplicateChars(text)) //Answer: 3 >> which says "l", "o" and "e" are duplicated characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go through the string to find the count of the duplicates. you can just subtract the count and the not duplicated version called `Set`.

```
func countDuplicates(_ s: String) -> Int { s.count - Set(s).count) }
```

---

### Note

You should consider maybe there will be more than one duplicated character there. So you need to find all duplicates for example by grouping similar and then count them:

```
let duplications = Dictionary(grouping: text, by: {$0}).map { [$0.key: $0.value.count] }
print(duplications)
```

---

You can get the sum of the duplicated ones if you want:

```
let totalDuplicationCount = dups.filter {$0.count > 1}.reduce(into: 0) { $0 += $1.count - 1 }
print(totalDuplicationCount)
```